# The Inner Sanctum Sealed Door and Objective 1C

Tags: mansions-of-madness

Yesterday, we played the Mansions of Madness core scenario, **The Inner Sanctum** I can't remember the exact options that I selected, but the final objective was **1C**, where the investigators we're being lured into the mansion to be fed to the monsters and Mary, the person we are attempting to find, was being held in the ceremony room.

Now, the final clue was placed in the ceremony room, the room that has **two** sealed door markers on it and no other entrances that I could see. This room also has a lock card.

My question is: how are the investigators supposed to interact with the lock card if they can't even attempt to move into the room due to the sealed doors? I double and triple checked the setup of the cards and I couldn't find anything that had been set up incorrectly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you must have had either the Furnace or Ceremony rooms in the wrong orientation, because there's a connecting door from the Basement to the Furnace Room to the Ceremony Room, via the 'top' of the Ceremony room tile. From the Investigator Guide:

[image: Map Setup from the Investigator Guide]